# Bottom borders on WPF Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, border, wpf-grid

I'd like to set a bottom border on each row in the grid, but can only find how to put all 4 borders around each cell..

```
<Grid Height="174" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,289,0,0" Name="grid2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="730">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="45" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="255" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="95" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="95" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="95" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="95" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="95" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

For another grid I'm using that needs all four borders, I'm using

```
<Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="#61738B" BorderThickness="1" />
```

P.S. The contents of the grid are some labels, textboxes, etc.. if that matters at all.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

On a `Border` control You can do `BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"` to only have a bottom border shown.

Top and bottom border thickness of 5, left and right border thickness of 0

`BorderThickness="0 5"`

Top and bottom border thickness of 0, left and right border thickness of 5

`BorderThickness="5 0"`

Border Thickness - Left: 1, Top: 2, Right:3, Bottom: 4

`BorderThickness="1 2 3 4"`

Comment: oh lord, it was that simple? Thanks a million! Another quick question - is there a way I can set the border on the entire row, without having to specify Grid.Column?

Comment: No problem! To my knowledge, I don't know if you can define a Row's border in the RowDefinition. If you're talking about having your border in a particular row span multiple columns, you can use Grid.ColumnSpan. Not sure if that's what you mean, but hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Pwninstein Grid.ColumnSpan helps, it places a border across each of column, now I've just gotta figure out how to have it repeat on each row without having 6 different <Border> declarations :)

Comment: Yeah... if it were me writing it, I'd probably just end up having 6 different `Border`s, I don't know of a way to do that either (I'd be glad to hear a way if someone knows one!)

Comment: I've set HorizontalAlignment=Right and those borders painted only for text lenght, if I remove this the borders are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had luck putting a bottom border on a whole row by including a Border Node with `BorderThickness="0 1 0 1"` surrounding the Grid Node.  Like this:

```
Border Style="{StaticResource ItemBorderStyle}" BorderThickness="0 1 0 1"
            Grid Style="{StaticResource GridItemStyle}"
```